# MacBook Air - unable to access websites without http/https

Tags: macbook-pro, web-browser, websites, http

I am using a MacBook air and I am unable to go to websites unless I specify http or https

My version is 10.10.5

Websites which automatically have https work like youtube.com and netflix.com

cnn.com does not work.

Comment: What web browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome but it happens on all browsers

Comment: does it do this on other computers on your network? Does it do this on other networks?

Comment: Could you please elaborate? If it is happening to all macs, it may be an issue with your router.

Comment: Not. it is just happening on my MAC. And it has happened in all networks and  in different countries as well. Something with the DNS setting but not sure

Comment: Did you manually configure your network on the Mac (i.e. you didn't just choose from the dropdown and enter the password)

Comment: no what does that mean? What am I supposed to configure?

Answer (score 1):

This might be because of your DNS. Simply try changing the DNS and it should work. 
Open Network settings and try changing your present DNS to Google Public DNS and it should get fixed.

Google Public DNS :

- 8.8.8.8
- 8.8.4.4

Comment: Hi That still did not work. Should I add IPV6 options too?

Comment: @HP No. Don't change them

Comment: I just have the above two entries and it is still not working.